# Resource to solve messed up words which have spaces in the wrong places

Tags: letters

I'm wondering if there are any online tools that solve *not properly spaced words*

By *not properly spaced words* I mean something like

> mynei ghbor isapo pular softw areen ginee r

if spaced properly, this should be

> my neighbor is a popular software engineer

Comment: Tryfirsttoremoveallspacesandresolvefromhere.

Comment: This is kinda ridiculous, but you could put it into quipqiup.com, which will deduce that the spaces are nonsense and then try to solve it as a simple substitution cipher. It'll have no idea that there's anything special about the solution a=a, b=b, c=c, etc., but my guess is that usually it'll work fine. (If it doesn't successfully work out that the spaces are bogus, you can explicitly tell it so.) I tried this on your example and it worked well.